# Killing a "personalized" Interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I've made this system so users can login to my website and play a game that requires some interval timing. When the user is done with playing I basically want to kill the interval. While everything seems to be running fine, there is something wrong with killing the interval.

**Here is the problem** Whenever a user is done playing the interval gets killed, not only for the user playing but for **everyone**. This might be because I'm assigning a variable to the interval and when a user is done playing a game I'm killing the `interval`, am I right that it then would kill the other intervals as well?

Here is some code I've written for this question,

```
var user; //this is a variable that has all info about the user. (its not usually empty)
var usersPlaying = [];

socket.on('game', function(game) {

    if(game.type == "start"){
        usersPlaying.push({
            user_id: user.id
        });

        var game = setInterval(function(){
            if(findUser(user.id) !== undefined){
                console.log('Second passed!');
            }else{
                clearInterval(game); //stop the interval
            }
        }, 1000);
    }else if(game.type == "stop"){

        console.log("User has decided to quit playing the game!");
        usersPlaying.splice(usersPlaying.findIndex(user => user === user.id), 1); //remove user from playing

    }

});
```

There might be some mistakes in there since I rewritten and simplified the code otherwise it would be way to hard to help me out.

Anyways, how can I make it so it only clears the interval running for a certain specified person?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you reusing the name `game` for the game socket message *and* the interval id? This is always, always a bad idea. Use clear names for your variables and definitely don't use the same variable for multiple purposes by changing its value halfway through a function. I have a feeling if you just use a proper name for the return value of `setInterval` it may solve your issue.

Comment: Did my answer help you?
The problem you are having is basically because you are using the global scope (reusing the same global variable for all the timers) so its better to use its own scope for each player (storing inside the socket or a global json that contains an object or the timer for each socket.id). Hope it helped

Comment: @philraj sorry thats just a mistake I made, in the actual code it isn't that way.

Comment: @EMX you mean I should have a global interval running counting for each player or something and removing them from the interval? idk what you are trying to tell me, I don't quite understand what you mean with scope and stuff, could you elaborate (not because you aren't explaining it well, just because I'm not understanding)

Comment: you need a unique interval for each player, (with unique reference to it). so you can perfectly store it as a value inside a json or whatever. that reference is important for future access (killing specifically that timer). Thats why I came up with using the socket object, since for each client the socket variable is a reference to that specific client object.

Comment: @MartijnEbbens If it's not like that in the actual code, show the actual code. :-) Otherwise it's hard to tell what's going wrong here. I don't think it's an issue of global scope, because you're saving the interval to a variable within the isolated scope of each socket's `game` message handler (which is then captured by the closure formed by the anonymous function you pass to `setInterval`).

Comment: @philraj it's nearly 700 lines, I would rather not have you sit here for an hour trying to discover flaws in my code, I'd rather simplify it for the guys that want to take the time to help me (:

Comment: I just meant for those few lines in particular. Sorry I can't be of more help, I just don't see anything jumping out in this example aside from the reuse of the variable name which I guess doesn't happen in the real version.

Comment: @philraj yeah, but let me ask this, how would you cancel/assign a interval that needs to be killed in another function?

Comment: Well, I'd probably maintain a list of open sockets, and associate each socket with data about the user who opened it and their game. You could have an object where the keys are socket IDs, and the values hold all the metadata. Then when you receive a socket message of type `game start`, you can start your interval and store the `clearInterval` return value on the socket's data in your list (`sockets[socket.id].game.interval = clearInterval(...)`). And when you receive `game stop`, lookup the existing interval using the socket ID and clear it. I would also make them separate events.

Comment: Another option would be to have a global interval, which iterates through a list of currently open sockets, and only performs the active game functions if the socket's data indicates `playing: true`. And on `game stop` you could set `playing: false`, and the interval will no longer do calculations for that client.

_(We might wanna move this into chat if more discussion is needed)_

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval` call returns a unique id. You can use that id to clear that interval timer afterwards:

```
var uniqueId = setInterval(function () { /* ... */ }, 1000);
```

Later on ...

```
clearInterval(uniqueId);
```

will kill that specific timer.

I suggest storing the uniqueId for each user inside the `usersPlaying` array.

Comment: Its not so good to use global variables... It can become a mess, you already have an object for each client with its unique id (socket.id) it would be wiser to store data for that client inside that clients object

Comment: How would I then be able to clear the interval, I'm confused, when I launch the interval I need some way to access it from the other game.type. How would I be able to then cancel the interval from the other game.type if I haven't assigned a variable to it?

Comment: You already have a  usersPlaying array that is an array of objects.  Store uniqueId inside the object for that particular user.

Comment: Sorry if I'm just beeing a nobhead here, but if I'd say .push({ interval: uniqueId}); and then clear the interval, wouldn't it just clear everyones interval because its also variable `uniqueId` for anyone and everyone else

Answer (score 0):

Store the interval for that specific socket inside its own scope :

```
var user; //this is a variable that has all info about the user. (its not usually empty)
var usersPlaying = [];

socket.on('game', function(game) {

    if(game.type == "start"){
        usersPlaying.push({
            user_id: user.id
        });

        socket.game = setInterval(function(){
            if(findUser(user.id) !== undefined){
                console.log('Second passed!');
            }else{
                clearInterval(socket.game); //stop the interval
            }
        }, 1000);
    }else if(game.type == "stop"){

        console.log("User has decided to quit playing the game!");
        usersPlaying.splice(usersPlaying.findIndex(user => user === user.id), 1); //remove user from playing

    }

});
```

So you can also kill it when disconnections occur :

```
socket.on('disconnecting',function(){
  if(socket.game){clearInterval(socket.game);}
});
```

EDIT :

```
var user; //this is a variable that has all info about the user. (its not usually empty)
```

better store all that inside the scope of the socket (each client  socket object in the server will have its own "user" key instead of making use of ugly global variables

So store it like `socket.user = {id:"foo"}` and you can access the specific user object for that client performing the socket event request like `if(findUser(socketuser.id) !== undefined){`

Comment: I want it to die after the user presses a stop button.

Comment: make an event like the disconnecting example... but you should think about **what if a disconnection occurs without him pressing that button?** thats why is good to have a handler for the disconnecting event also

Comment: that doesn't matter if it continues, because its a game of chance and it can stop at any given moment.

Comment: So you dont mind intervals running (consuming resources) for a user that isnt even connected? :P

Comment: yes, I do, but users should have the chance to reconnect.

Comment: then I would use a JSON Object instead of storing it in the socket (the socket is destroyed on disconnection) and store the timer and the socket.id inside that JSON instead of the array  you are using. also, instead of using the socket.id I would use the username as a key so if he wants to reconnect you can rejoin the same timer, or if the username logs in from a different window / device you will be able to notify the older client, and using json is easy to access and faster than pushing and deleting from arrays

Comment: Yeah, the id is linked to the user, it has nothing to do with socket. How would you then store the timer in the object I made? I mean the object is not inside the actual socket. Could I do usersPlaying.push(interval:setInterval(function(){})); but I feel like that would be a, sorry to say, stupid move.

Comment: It would be wiser to store the user.id inside the socket for reference of the user accont and change  `usersPlaying ` from `[]` (array) to an `{}` (object) so you can do  `usersPlaying[socket.user.id].timer = setInterval... `

Comment: so it's not a stupid move to just throw in the complete interval? I feel like that would not be the best solution?

Comment: It is stupid using an array because how do you access the specific interval for a specific user... then you have to store the array index, and the index may vary if you delete a low number... I suggest you learn more JS... :P Using an object would be the way to go with your current setup...

Comment: Sorry to say so, but being told "I suggest you learn more JS" doesn't motivate me in trying, this is actually me learning how javascript works and this is my way of learning by discussing possible options which is in my opinion the best way to learn, I'm currently trying it out and hoping for the best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152369/discussion-between-emx-and-martijn-ebbens).